# Dapper insert, check for existence of record

Tags: c#, dapper

So i have been using this method to insert records into my database:

```
TransactionBlock.Connection.Execute(
                            "INSERT Table(Item,Id)VALUES(@Item, @Id);
                            new {Item,Id = id }, TransactionBlock.Transaction);
```

I now need to modify this, to first check if the Item/id are already in the database, using the following:

const sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table, where Item=@Item...etc etc

but I've not come across any examples of how to achieve this. I can achieve this by creating a Stored Procedure, but i'd like to try and accomplish using this approach.

Comment: This isn't so much a Dapper issue, more of an SQL one. Which backend are you using SQL Server, MSSQL, Oracle etc.?

Comment: SQL Server. I can achieve what i want using pure SP's being called from Dapper, just not sure how to present the inline check using dapper. Agreed, not a direct issue with dapper, just howto:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and that you only want to insert the record if it doesn't already exist the SQL you are looking for is

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id = @Id) 
    INSERT INTO Table(Item, Id) VALUES(@Item, @Id)
```

Comment: personally I'd make it a `WHERE` clause on the `INSERT`, rather than 2 separate operations

Comment: @MarcGravell, how it can be done? `insert Table(Item, Id) VALUES(@Item, @Id) WHERE Id <> @Id` fails for me with error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Comment: @user854301 try `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Id = @Id)`

Comment: @user854301 if you want to do it in one step, see Matt's answer; however, the SQL shown here is fine too

Comment: @MarcGravell, finnaly got it. i've replaced `values` with `select`, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Item, ID)
SELECT @Item, @Id WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Id=@Id )
```

That will work with one single statement.

Worth noting that depending on the underlying DBMS, you may still have contention - if no lock is issued and many inserts are happening simultaneously you can end up in a condition where the record doesn't exist when it executes the select, but does before it attempts the insert.

If you're dealing with a situation where inserts are happening rapidly, I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with the following:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Rather than checking if it exists before insertion why not use a try/catch clock to perform the insertion and catch the DuplicateKeyException (not sure if it exists) to determine duplicate.

Comment: Downvote. Why would you catch exceptions if you can prevent them? Doesn't 'feel' right.

Comment: @avb1994, because if you're inserting 100,000 items in a table and may be 10% would be duplicate it makes sense to systematically insert and detect exception for duplicate. Otherwise you're performing 100,000 reads for each insert. That was my rationale.

Comment: Exceptions are very costly and shouldn't be used to control logic flow.

Comment: Every time you throw an exception, a small village is burned down.

Comment: @Raj you aren't avoiding that read. The server has to read the index values to determine if there's a violation. Exceptions and errors are far more expensive anyway, because they *aren't* supposed to occur frequently